# Integral of a function defined itself as a non elementary inetgral with parametric limits

Tags: numerical-integration

Suppose I have a function $g(t)$ defined as $$ g(t)=\int_0^{1-t}e^{(u^n+sin u)}du ,\quad  n \in N$$.
There is nothing special with the integrand ,you can replace it by any other function whose indefinite inetgral is not computable in a closed form.What I am not able to figure out is how we can numerically compute an integral of ,say,
$$ I= \int_0^1 t^2 g(t) dt $$ that involves $g(t)$ in Mathematica.Lots of thanks for any hints/ suggestions/responces!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you include the definition of $g$ as plain text Mathematica code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, may this will work

```
ClearAll[g, t, u]
g[t_?NumericQ, n_Integer] := NIntegrate[Exp[u^n + Sin[u]], {u, 0, 1 - t}]
n = 99;
NIntegrate[t^2*g[t, n], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]